# Why is formattable ignoring my conditional formatting?

Tags: r, formattable

I'm trying to only highlights the word with "yes" under column "YesNo" but it isn't working.. am I doing it in a wrong way?

```
    df = data.frame(YesNo = c("yes","no","yes","no"), 
                Numbers = c(4, 5, 10, 10))
df

rownames(df) = c("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4")
df
```

[image: The error I get]

```
formattable(df)


sign_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                            style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x == "yes", "green", 
                                                             ifelse(x =="no", "red", "black"))))

    formattable(df, list(
      YesNo = sign_formatter,
      Numbers = color_tile("transparent","lightgreen")))
```

Comment: It is working fine based on the condition i..e I am getting 'yes' with green color and 'no' with 'red' What is the expected output

Comment: I'm not getting any condition output.. I get an error instead.. I just edited my post, u can see the error I got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not related to the code.  It is because of masking of functions of `formattable` from `plotly`.  There are a bunch of functions that are common in both and once the `plotly` package is loaded after the `formattable`, the same function will be masked by the `plotly` function.  Remedy is

1. Either do this on a fresh `R` session with only `formattable` loaded
2. Use `::` to suggest the function is from that package

Probably the issue is with `style` which `plotly` also have

```
library(formattable)
sign_formatter <- formattable::formatter("span", 
                            style = x ~ 
      formattable::style(color = ifelse(x == "yes", "green", 
                            ifelse(x =="no", "red", "black"))))

formattable::formattable(df, list(
  YesNo = sign_formatter,
  Numbers = formattable::color_tile("transparent","lightgreen")))
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df = data.frame(YesNo = c("yes","no","yes","no"), 
                Numbers = c(4, 5, 10, 10))
df

rownames(df) = c("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4")
```

---

To create a condition based on the first 'n' rows or so

```
n <- 2
sign_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                            style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(seq_along(x) <= n & x == "yes", "green", 
                                                             ifelse(seq_along(x) <= n & x =="no", "red", "black"))))

formattable(df, list(
  YesNo = sign_formatter,
  Numbers = color_tile("transparent","lightgreen")))
```

-output
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to show the first 10 rows with the condition on... example in r, head(df, 10)